# How to parse the collections in `mongodump` archive output using Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodump

#### Context

I have a MongoDB that is backed up every day using the following command

```
mongodump --gzip --numParallelCollections=1 --oplog --archive=/tmp/dump.gz --readPreference=primary
```

I want to parse this dump file using python only, to get all the underlying BSON documents.
I want to convert the BSON into JSON.

#### What I tried

Let's say I have a single db named `my_db` and a single collection named `my_employees` which contains two documents only

```
{"name": "john doe"}
{"name": "jane doe"}
```

I dumped this single collection using the following command

```
mongodump --readPreference=primary --gzip --archive=/tmp/dump.gz --numParallelCollections=1 --db=my_db --collection=my_employees
```

I `gunzip` the dump file.

Now I try to parse the file using only `python` and `pymongo`. I try to take inspiration from this Go [parser](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/blob/master/common/archive/parser.go).

I don't know Go but what I understood is that the dump file contains zero or more blocks each block has the following structure

```
terminator_or_size_of_bson: 4 bytes
bson_document: N bytes
```

Here is the code I came up with (it doesn't handle a lot of things, but it's quick draft)

```py
import bson

dump = open("/tmp/dump", "rb").read() # I `gunziped` the file before
file_size = len(dump)

i = 0
nb_bsons_to_parse = 10 # I try to print the first 10 BSONS
bsons_parsed = 0

while i < file_size and bsons_parsed < nb_bsons_to_parse:
    bson_size = int.from_bytes(dump[i: i+4], "little")
    print("here is the bson_size ", bson_size)
    print("here is the bson_size in bytes ", dump[i: i + 4])
    bson_document_bytes = dump[i+4: i + 4 + bson_size]
    bson_document = bson.decode_all(bson_document_bytes)
    print(bson_document)
    nb_bsons_to_parse += 1
    i += i + 4 + bson_size
```

here is the error I have

```
here is the bson_size  2174345837
here is the bson_size in bytes  b'm\xe2\x99\x81'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..../read_bson_from_dump.py", line 27, in <module>
    bson_document = bson.decode_all(bson_document_bytes)
bson.errors.InvalidBSON: invalid message size
```

You can see that the first four bytes have a value `2174345837` that exceeds the allowed 16MB document [size](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/blob/460c7e26f65c4ce86a0b99c46a559dccaba3a07d/common/db/db.go#L50)

I used a different BSON API

```py
# ... only this loop changes 
while i < file_size and bsons_parsed < nb_bsons_to_parse:
    bson_size = int.from_bytes(dump[i: i+4], "little")
    print("here is the bson_size ", bson_size)
    print("here is the bson_size in bytes ", dump[i: i + 4])
    bson_document_bytes = dump[i+4: i + 4 + bson_size]
    itr = bson.decode_iter(bson_document_bytes)
    for rec in itr:
        print(rec)
        nb_bsons_to_parse += 1
    i += i + 4 + bson_size
```

And here is the result I have

```
here is the bson_size  2174345837
here is the bson_size in bytes  b'm\xe2\x99\x81'
{'concurrent_collections': 1, 'version': '0.1', 'server_version': '4.4.13', 'tool_version': '100.5.2'}
{'db': 'my_db', 'collection': 'my_employees', 'metadata': '{"indexes":[{"v":{"$numberInt":"2"},"key":{"_id":{"$numberInt":"1"}},"name":"_id_"}],"uuid":"525124e3292340ce92048df1bc16189c","collectionName":"my_employees","type":"collection"}', 'size': 0, 'type': 'collection'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..../read_bson_from_dump.py", line 28, in <module>
    for rec in itr:
  File ".../env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bson/__init__.py", line 1061, in decode_iter
    yield _bson_to_dict(elements, codec_options)
bson.errors.InvalidBSON: not enough data for a BSON document
```

I don't want to use `mongoexport` nor `mongrestore` to parse the archive dump.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

I already parse the mongodump archive using nodejs
the first 4 bytes of the archive are the magic number not the size of the documents.
after the magic number, the first bson data is the archive header with the value of

```
{
  concurrent_collections: 4,
  version: '0.1',
  server_version: '4.2.2',
  tool_version: 'r4.2.2'
}
```

the next bson data is all your collections with index information, you need to loop this until the first terminator with the value of 0xffffffff
then the next bson data is all your documents until the last terminator

Comment: Do you know if it would be possible to use data from the header to "jump" to the document section corresponding to a given collection? I'm working on a backup containing more collections that I need and it would be nice to skip some of them.